# setting quota on nfs mount - not working

Tags: centos, nfs, quota

I have some issues with setting quota on an nfs drive, despite following all instructions from chatgpt. Here is the setup:

the nfs server has an ext4 drive, mounted as below (/etc/fstab):

`UUID=XXXX /disk2        ext4    defaults,quota  0 0`

i also exported this drive:

`/disk2 10.xx.yy.zz/24(rw,sync)`

on my client, i have tried to mount this drive via nfs, seee /etc/fstab line below:

`server:/disk2        /disk2  nfs     rw,usrquota,grpquota    0 0`

and here is what it said:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

###########################

yes i know that in the server it should be having "usrquota" in the /etc/exports file, but when i added that in, it reports errors:

```
[root@server~]# cat /etc/exports
/disk2 10.xx.yy.zz/24(rw,sync,quota)
[root@server~]# exportfs -rav
exportfs: /etc/exports:1: unknown keyword "quota"

exportfs: No file systems exported!

[root@server~]# cat /etc/exports
/disk2 10.xx.yy.zz/24(rw,sync,usrquota)
[root@server~]# exportfs -rav
exportfs: /etc/exports:1: unknown keyword "usrquota"

exportfs: No file systems exported!
```

Since i could not export this on the server, the client won't be able to mount it either.

Wonder if any suggestions to get this (setting user quota on a centOS8 client with a drive mounted via nfs from a centOS8 server where the drive is formatted on ext4) done?

Thanks!

-Swatow

Comment: any comments from our admin friends? appreciated!